# how to read and write to oracle 11g db using php

Tags: php, angularjs, oracle11g, oracle-call-interface

I am new to Angular JS and PHP and here is what I plan to do

1. Use Angular JS for front end.
2. Use PHP to read and write data from DB and send it to Angular JS

I am trying to use oci_connect calls to connect to oracle DB and here is what displayed in the browser when I run the php file.

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function oci_connect()
```

I tried following the steps mentioned over here
http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php

PHP is pre-installed on my linux box and I am not sure how can I run configure (from which directory)
I am using the PHP server on the same host where my database is. How can I verify that the OCI libraries are installed? I added the following line in php.ini

```
extension=oci8.so
```

and restarted the apache server but no luck :(

Here is my php code.

```
<?php
ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(-1);

$conn = oci_connect('username','password','http://host:port/SID');

if (!$conn) {
    $e = oci_error();
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
// Prepare the statement
$stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT * FROM employees');
if (!$stid) {
    $e = oci_error($conn);
    //trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
// Perform the logic of the query
$r = oci_execute($stid);
if (!$r) {
    $e = oci_error($stid);
    trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
// Fetch the results of the query
print "<table border='1'>\n";
while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    print "<tr>\n";
    foreach ($row as $item) {
        print " <td>" . ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;") . "    </td>\n";
    }
    print "</tr>\n";
}
print "</table>\n";
oci_free_statement($stid);
oci_close($conn);
?>
```

Appreciate the help!!

Comment: check `phpinfo()`. if it doesn't show the oracle stuff, then the module isn't being loaded by php. either the .so file can't be found, or something else is preventing it from loading - in which case you should also look at the webserver's error logs for any clues.

Comment: You will need to re-compile php to include the `--with-oci8` flag ([oracle step by step guide](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/technote-php-instant-084410.html)). I've also had success working with zend server which has an admin panel that allows you to add/remove extensions pretty easily. But that is essentially installing a new php version.